# Requests library get method error in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping

When I try to use the requests lib `get` method I get an error:

(using tkinter)

The error comes from this line:

```
var.set(get('https://api.ipify.org').text)
```

the error message says :

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Comment: Are you behind a firewall. If u so you might have to provide a proxy

Comment: This has nothing to do with tkinter.  You'll get the same error without. I recommend creating a [mcve] that doesn't include tkinter. That will make it much easier to debug.

Comment: i still get the same error and for now i'm using it in python shell                                                              from requests import *                                                                                        ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text    @BryanOakley